# Creating a dataframe from a dictionary within tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary within a tuple and I want to know how to access it and create a dataframe merging the dictionary value into single row

```
Example:

({'Id': '4', 'BU': 'usa', 'V_ID': '44', 'INV': 'inv1331', 'DT': '08/1/19', 'AMT': '1500'}, {'Id': '9', 'BU': 'usa', 'V_ID': '44', 'INV': 'inv4321', 'DT': '02/6/19', 'AMT': '1000'})

Expected Result:

Id_1  BU_1  V_ID_1  INV_1     DT_1    AMT_1   Id_2  BU_2  V_ID_2  INV_2    DT_2     AMT_2  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4     usa    44   inv1331   08/1/19  1500     9     usa    44    inv4321   02/6/19  1000
```

Comment: You can use the `csv` module to export a list of dicts into a csv file....

Comment: You could first write a function which takes such a tuple of dictionaries and turns it into a single dictionary. In any event, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ({'Id': '4', 'BU': 'usa', 'V_ID': '44', 'INV': 'inv1331', 'DT': '08/1/19', 'AMT': '1500'}, {'Id': '9', 'BU': 'usa', 'V_ID': '44', 'INV': 'inv4321', 'DT': '02/6/19', 'AMT': '1000'})

data = {f"{k}_{i+1}": v for i, d in enumerate(x) for k, v in d.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [0])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
  Id_1 BU_1 V_ID_1    INV_1     DT_1  ... BU_2 V_ID_2    INV_2     DT_2 AMT_2
0    4  usa     44  inv1331  08/1/19  ...  usa     44  inv4321  02/6/19  1000

[1 rows x 12 columns]
```